# Publish with new update

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, vercel

I created a project in Flutter Web + Lazy Loading.
After updating project I'm running: Flutter Build Web
Then I put the project in the service of Vercel.
When I access the site I noticed that it is not downloading the new updates and generating blank pages when closing the site and opens again works.

Do I need to define the new version somewhere in the project and run: Flutter Build Web and post again to avoid this problem again?

By accessing the site all files are downloaded again by preventing the cache from undermining the user experience.